# Got stuck. See the body below

Tags: python

Got stuck.

In Python, a dictionary can only hold a single value for a given key. To workaround this, our single value can be a list containing multiple values. Here we have a dictionary called "wardrobe" with items of clothing and their colors. Fill in the blanks to print a line for each item of clothing with each color, for example: "red shirt", "blue shirt", and so on.

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}

for __:
    for __:
        print("{} {}".format(__))`
```

This is MAX of what I wrote.

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for key, value in wardrobe.items():
    for i in value:
        print("{} {}".format(value, key))
Output: 
Here is your output:
['red', 'blue', 'white'] shirt
['red', 'blue', 'white'] shirt
['red', 'blue', 'white'] shirt
['blue', 'black'] jeans
['blue', 'black'] jeans
```

Not quite. Remember that we first want to iterate through
    the elements of the dictionary and then through the elements
    of the list.

Comment: You probably meant `print("{} {}".format(i, key))`, since `i` contains the selected value for the loop? Maybe you should replace `value` by `values` or `valueList` and than `i` by `value` to make the variable names match their content. I guess it's only a typo, thus I vote to close it. The question is unlikely to help future readers with similar problems.
As a side note: For future questions, please find a title for your question, which actually *is* a titel.

Comment: Please make sure to **ask a question** when posting. "Got stuck" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/). "Remember that we first want to iterate through the elements of the dictionary and then through the elements of the list." Okay, so **what was unclear** about this feedback?

Answer (score 3):

Try to run this code:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for key, value in wardrobe.items():
    for i in value:
        print("{} {}".format(i, key))
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
count=0
for key, value in wardrobe.items():
    for i in value:
    if count <3:
        print("{} shirt".format(i))
        count+=1
    else:
        print("{} jeans".format(i))
```

produces output

```
red shirt
blue shirt
white shirt
blue jeans
black jeans
```

Comment: Here is your output:
red shirt
blue shirt
white shirt
blue jeans
black jeans

Answer (score 1):

In `print("{} {}".format(value, key))`, kindly replace value with i.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer accepted by Google:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for key, value in wardrobe.items():
    for i in value:
        print("{} {}".format(i, key))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for key, values in wardrobe.items():
    for value in values:
        print("{} {}".format(value, key))
```

[image: This is exact code to your answer]

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps!,

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for color, clothings in wardrobe.items():
    for clothing in clothings:
        print("{} {}".format(clothing,color))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
for keys,values in wardrobe.items():
    for value in values:
        print("{} {}".format(value,keys))
```